# Rapid Application Development in Eclipse Alfresco (Hot Reloading)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, alfresco, reloading

I want to make changes in the SendAsEmailActionExecuter.java file in the sub-project AMP (add-action-repo) which is inside All-in-one project in Alfresco 5 community. It is an example as you can see in the [following link](http://docs.alfresco.com/sdk2.1/tasks/alfresco-sdk-rad-eclipse-hot-reloading.html). I am developing in eclipse and when I customize an ftl or js file the eclipse the eclipse reload the changes. How can achieve the same thing with java file without the need to execute clean install -Prun command every time.

I have notice this [guide](http://docs.alfresco.com/sdk2.1/tasks/alfresco-sdk-rad-eclipse-hot-reloading.html) but the DemoComponentTest does not make the trick.

How can achieve hot reloading in a such case ?

Answer (score 2):

The Rapid Application Development (RAD) in Alfresco SDK is delivered by the spring loaded library.

Long story short, you need to run your project using the shipped OOTB run.sh / run.bat depending on your OS.

The run script will check if the spring-loaded jar is already present in your repo, run profile setup if it is not present to go fetch it, and then run `mvn integration-test -Prun` or `mvn install -Prun`, I do not remember which is called on the script but it should be one of those two

---

**UPDATE :**

- Please refer to [this file](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/blob/alfresco-sdk-aggregator-2.1.1/archetypes/alfresco-allinone-archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/run.sh) for further reference
- Please note that [RAD is not available in SDK-2.2](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2016/03/04/introducing-alfresco-sdk-2-2/) as it is not compatible with it and would prevent the repo from starting
- SDK 2.2 is only available for alfresco 5.1.x code base (and it is the only viable option for developing 5.1.x extensions)

Comment: I try both of commands with no result. I notice that in order to achieve hot reload in java you need Jrebel http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/dev-extensions-maven-sdk-tutorials-jrebel-intro.html

Comment: You should try `run.sh`