# All-in-one extension - Actions doesn't work

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm using Alfresco 5.1 Community and SDK 2.2. I migrate my project to [All-in-one](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/alfresco-sdk-tutorials-all-in-one-archetype.html) extension to make a [Rapid Application Development (RAD)](http://docs.alfresco.com/sdk2.1/concepts/alfresco-sdk-rad.html) .
I have two custom document library actions, that works without the all-in-one extension, but here, doesn't appear the image of the button and doesn't open the pages that is supposed (and doesn't give any error...).

There are any reason for this?

Another question, I get this: Failed to Refresh Web Scripts for Alfresco Share. Response status: 401, message: Unauthorized on IntelliJ, when I'm trying to run the project all-in-one with (alt+f9).

The error that I get  in the shell: http://pastebin.com/wxpXEEKa

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the SDK / Alfresco are you on ? Can you share your project tree ?

Comment: SDK 2.2, Alfresco 5.1 Community . My project tree you want all the folders open? The error that I obtain in the shell, I forgot to include. I update my question with all information. @YounesRegaieg

Comment: No need for folder tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already explained in a [former answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35800118/2307988), RAD has been disabled by default in SDK 2.2 since Spring Loaded would currently prevent the repo from starting up, according to [the official release notes for SDK 2.2](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2016/03/04/introducing-alfresco-sdk-2-2/) .

Comment: And now we can't make a RADevelopment? Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Not on alfresco 5.1 code line, at least until SDK 3.0 is released !  
You could use SDK 2.1.1 with Alfresco 5.0 if RAD is that crucial to you! And the produced amps **should*** be compatible with Alfresco 5.1 as well